# Modify component state after a promise resolve

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to modify a component's state (react native) after a promise is resolved.

Here is my code:

```
    class Greeting extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {text: 'Starting...'};

        var handler = new RequestHandler();
        handler.login('email','password')
        .then(function(resp){
            this.setState({text:resp});
        });
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <Text style={this.props.style}>
                Resp: {this.state.text}
            </Text>
        );
    }
}
```

But when the promise resolve, it throws the following error:

```
this.setState is not a function
TypeError: this.setState is not a function
    at http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:1510:6
    at tryCallOne (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:25187:8)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:25273:9
    at JSTimersExecution.callbacks.(anonymous function) (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:8848:13)
    at Object.callTimer (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:8487:1)
    at Object.callImmediatesPass (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:8586:19)
    at Object.callImmediates (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:8601:25)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:7395:43
    at guard (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:7288:1)
    at MessageQueue.__callImmediates (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:7395:1)
```

How can I change the current Component state after a promise is resolved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The callback has a **different context than the object you are working with**. For this reason, `this` is not what you think it is.

---

To solve this, you can use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which keeps the surrounding context:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {text: 'Starting...'};

    var handler = new RequestHandler();
    handler.login('email','password')
        .then(resp => this.setState({text:resp}));
}
```

---

Alternatively, set the function context manually using [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {text: 'Starting...'};

    var handler = new RequestHandler();
    handler.login('email','password')
        .then(function(resp){
            this.setState({text:resp});
        }.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use new syntax. more here https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus

```
class Greeting extends Component{
    state = {
      text: 'Starting...',
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      var handler = new RequestHandler();
      handler.login('email','password')
        .then((text) => {
            this.setState({ text });
        })
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <Text style={this.props.style}>
                Resp: {this.state.text}
            </Text>
        );
    }
}
```